# Mysqli connection issue fatal error

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have the below code:

```
class config_model
{
    public $host;
    public $root;
    public $root_password;
    public $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->root = "root";
        $this->root_password = "";
        $this->db = "Data";
    }

    public function init() {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->root, $this->root_password, $this->db);
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        return $mysqli;
    }
}

$config_model = new config_model();
echo $config_model->init();
```

When I check the script I see this error:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string".

The erorr is here: "**echo $config_model->init();**"

How do I handle this error?

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to call the `init()` function in the `__construct` call?

Comment: When I see people using `mysqli` instead of `pdo`, it makes me sad. It should really be deprecated.

Comment: @TheLaw MySQLi is not that bad, it can be used in OOP format and it's *almost* as good as PDO. It's perfectly usable and when handled correctly is seemless. PDO has a few more customisations and options up its sleeve but really that's no call for saying that MySQL*i*  is really practically any worse.

Comment: @Martin Well, yeah, it is not bad, until you decide you want to change the type of db to anything but MySQL somewhere down the line. Stuff like that happens and then you have to rewrite your database class and any occurrence of DB usage in your app. With PDO, DB switch is not such pain, since it probably already supports your DB.

Comment: @TheLaw But DB switching is a specific case scenario and totally irrelevant to this question. I have written my own DB interaction class using MySQLi (started off as a learning exercise and grew) and it can handle most (alas not all) things that PDO native class does. While PDO can be better than MySQLi in some specific instances, that's absolutely no reason that MySQLi should be removed `:-p`

Comment: @TheLaw most developers on a stable platform don't need to and shouldn't need to DB switch, if you're swapping between types of DB every few months there's a more fundamental issue with the business model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is this:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string".

now, read the error: it says ***Object of class mysqli not be converted to string***. Actually read it. Now, I hope you know what an object is, and I also hope you know what a string is. So the Object is somewhere being converted to a string and the object can't handle that conversion.

Where is this happening? Reading your code line by line and you even give the line the error occurs on:

> echo $config_model->init();

you are ***echoing*** out an object because that is what is being *return*ed by the `->init()` method call, init is giving you back an object type. You are then immediately telling PHP to output this object as a string type. ***This*** is causing the issue.

### Solution

PHP has a  [`__ToString()` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) which you can add to your object so that what you call it as a string (which you shouldn't, but...) that the object will run this magic method and output something of your designation.

A simpler solution is also not to try and output objects as strings, instead using routines such as `print_r` or `var_dump` if you really need to (but as stated, you shouldn't be doing this at all in a perfect world).

Answer (score 2):

the code `$config_model->init()` returns object of Config_model class, so you can not 'echo' it, because echo is used for string,
If you wan to test your configuration you may use `var_dump()`.

for Ex:

```
$config_model = new config_model();
var_dump($config_model->init());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
     $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;
} catch (Exception $e ) {
     echo "Service unavailable";
     echo "message: " . $e->message;   // not in live code obviously...
     exit;
}
```

Comment: This help thx, you can detailing why i have theat error from my code?

Comment: Sorry but this is the wrong way of dealing with this issue. There is no call to use exceptions to handle bad programming logic [bad programming is not exceptional]. This solution doesn't fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

$config_model = new config_model();

$config_model is object and cannot echo it, just use var_dump().